# Consulta SQL relacion de varios a varios

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Cuando hago la consulta de estas tres tablas me arroja muchos registros duplicados espero que me puedan ayudar el SQL es el siguiente

```
 SELECT indycomercio.*,
       citaciones.fecha_citacion,
       citaciones.fecha_taquilla,
       citaciones.fecha_prorroga,
       citaciones.se_presento,
       citaciones.ubicacion_exp,
       citaciones.status_contribuyente,
       fiscalizaciones.providencia,
       fiscalizaciones.fecha_fisc,
       fiscalizaciones.division,
       fiscalizaciones.fiscal,
       fiscalizaciones.coordinador,
       fiscalizaciones.cierre
FROM   (indycomercio
        INNER JOIN fiscalizaciones
                ON indycomercio.licencia = fiscalizaciones.licencia)
       INNER JOIN citaciones
               ON indycomercio.licencia = citaciones.licencia;
```

Comment: Te falta indicar qué quieres obtener de la consulta. Si muestras un par de registros de prueba en cada tabla y lo que quieres que salga como resultado, es más fácil ayudar. :)

Comment: Es básicamente una consulta que muestre la información de un establecimiento (IndYComercio) y las fiscalizaciones y multas que ha tenido

Comment: Básicamente no conocemos tu lógica de negocio como tú y los detalles que te indiqué son necesarios para poder construir una consulta que se ajuste a lo que buscas

Comment: Proyecta únicamente los campos que te interesen y usa `DISTINCT` tras el `SELECT` para no mostrar duplicados. Si necesitas más ayuda, tendrás que pasarnos el dataset con algún dato de ejemplo, como de indica @Alfabravo

Answer (score 0):

Una forma sencilla es solo agregando distinct

```
SELECT distinct indycomercio.*,
       citaciones.fecha_citacion,
       citaciones.fecha_taquilla,
       citaciones.fecha_prorroga,
       citaciones.se_presento,
       citaciones.ubicacion_exp,
       citaciones.status_contribuyente,
       fiscalizaciones.providencia,
       fiscalizaciones.fecha_fisc,
       fiscalizaciones.division,
       fiscalizaciones.fiscal,
       fiscalizaciones.coordinador,
       fiscalizaciones.cierre
FROM   (indycomercio
        INNER JOIN fiscalizaciones
                ON indycomercio.licencia = fiscalizaciones.licencia)
       INNER JOIN citaciones
               ON indycomercio.licencia = citaciones.licencia;
```

Eso te va a devolver las distintas combinaciones de los campos que seleccionas.
Como se menciona en un comentario anterior, hay que conocer mas la lógica del negocio para entender si se puede mejorar esta consulta SQL.

Espero te sirva!!

Abrazo.